# Different Significance in Stargazer for Standardised/Unstandardised Coefficients

Tags: r, linear-regression, stargazer, significance, standardized

I've performed a multiple linear regression on a large data set using

```
m1 <- lm(y ~ x + x1 + x2..., dataset)
```

added standardised beta coefficients using lm.beta

```
m1_stnd <- lm.beta(m1)
```

and tabulated the results using stargazer

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(m1, m1_stnd, coef = list(m1$coefficients,m1_stnd$standardized.coefficients), 
type = "text", digits = 3, covariate labels = c("labels", "labels2", "labels3",...), 
title = "Title", out = "m1_reg.htm")
```

The output gives me two columns of coefficients, however, the significance values are different for some of them, with the unstandardized often significant when the standardized are not

```
               Unstandardized     Standardized
Gender (Male)      -0.125***          -0.010
                   (0.048)            (0.048)
```

The answer to this post : [Including standardized coefficients in a stargazer table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076903/including-standardized-coefficients-in-a-stargazer-table) shows the same thing for the constant only (they don't comment on it), whereas I have it for many of my variables.

Why would this happen, is it an error in my code or is it statistically valid? I don't see how standardizing should change the significance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Stargazer is using the unstandardised coefficients to determine the significance of the standardised, because you have not told it otherwise. You need to add in another line detailing which p values to use:

`p = list (coef(summary(m1))[,4], coef(summary(m1))[,4])`:

The complete method call would look like:

```
stargazer(m1, m1_stnd, coef = list(m1$coefficients, m1_stnd$standardized.coefficients),
p = list (coef(summary(m1))[,4], coef(summary(m1))[,4]), 
type = "text",
digits = 3,
covariate labels = c("labels", "labels2", "labels3",...),
title = "Title",
out = "m1_reg.htm")
```

Comment: I have a similar problem where I have a logistic regression glm model and once I do "apply.coef=exp" to get the ORs, everything mysteriously turns significant. I'm guessing this is because it affects how the significance is determined, which is then based on the ORs... Do you know how I could change that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add in another line detailing which p values to use as already suggested. But, the correct column is 5, not 4 (the 4th column in lm.beta summary is t value), thus:

```
p = list (coef(summary(m1))[,5], coef(summary(m1))[,5])
```